# Page navigation WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I made an app to WP8 and I used the page navigation like `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(...))` and worked well.
But now I'm trying to develop a WP8.1 app and can't figure out how is it going.
I get the following error `The name 'NavigationService' does not exist in the current context`.
I have two pages and I want to navigate between them.
How can I do?
What changed?

Comment: Sigh, why did you delete your question? I thought it's a really good one and was ready to post an answer to it...

Comment: @JustinXL I found out that I was stupid, and it worked, I only had to decrease the changing value at the opacity form 0.1 to 0.01, and then everything worked, so I thought that I delete the question, because it's not program code related, just a value mistake.

Comment: Well, even so, I don't think it's the best approach. If you like, I can undelete it and post my answer for you to have a look.

Comment: you may right, so it'd be my pleasure

Comment: Ahh actually, I need 5 votes to undelete it. Would you be able to undelete it? Thanks!

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008698/dim-overlay-by-swiping-on-windows-phone) you go

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Universal Apps (Windows Runtime), you need to use the [`Frame.Navigate(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate) overload, with the type of the page you're navigating to.

To navigate to MainPage.xaml, you can use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));`

I'll recommend reading [Quickstart: Navigating between pages (Windows Runtime apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188)

Answer (score 3):

You can navigate using

> Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));