# Dim overlay by swiping on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, overlay, swipe

I have a rectangle as an overlay and I want to modify its opacity by swiping up and down, like in the app Free Talking Alarm Clock. I figured out, that I have to deal with `ManipulationStarted` and `ManipulationDelta` events, but not sure which value to use. At this point I'm able to change the opacity by swiping, but changes only when the swipe is completed, and I want the opacity to change while I'm swiping. How do I do that?

Right now, I have this:

```
private Point initialpoint;
private double opacity;
private void rec_overlay_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        initialpoint = e.Position;
    }

private void rec_overlay_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Point currentpoint = e.Position;

    if (initialpoint.Y - currentpoint.Y < 0)
    {
        opacity += 0.1;
        rec_overlay.Opacity = opacity;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Swipe down");
    }
    else if(initialpoint.Y - currentpoint.Y > 0)
    {
        opacity -= 0.1;
        rec_overlay.Opacity = opacity;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Swipe up");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the distance of your finger movement should be directly proportional to the `Rectangle`'s `Opacity` change.

You can monitor the *most recent Y change* which is `e.Delta.Translation.Y` and divide it by the `Rectangle`'s `ActualHeight` in order to get a more accurate `Opacity` change.

Something like this will do.

```
private void rec_overlay_ManipulationDelta(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // keep the Opacity value within its boundary
    if (rec_overlay.Opacity > 1)
    {
        rec_overlay.Opacity = 1;
    }
    else if (rec_overlay.Opacity < 0)
    {
        rec_overlay.Opacity = 0;
    }

    // update the opacity whenever a movement happens
    rec_overlay.Opacity += -e.Delta.Translation.Y / this.rec_overlay.ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: well, I made it inverse ..`acity -= -e.De`.. but it's much nicer and smoother than mine solution with the 0.01, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. :) Also maybe just += e.De... For readability

Answer (score 1):

the code above works, just have to change the opacity value from 0.1 to 0.01